# PHP and Javascript Communication

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, communication

```
<form action="../">
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
    <option value="92507">92507</option>
    <option value="30078">30078</option>
    <option value="92606">92606</option>
    <option value="30004">30004</option>
    <option value="32034">32034</option>
    <option value="37160">37160</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I have created a drop down menu where the user could select a zip code. I want to send the zipcode that the user has selected to a php script. How to go about this?

This is what I have done/understood so far. I need to add this line of code `$php_variable = $_GET['param1'];` in my php file which would get the zip code as param1 which the javascript sends over the url. I can use an ajax function in my javascript and call a post to send over the data. Am I on the right track? How do I actually save the user's selection of zip code into a variable. Also shouldn't the ajax be in a script? Can I also put the drop down menu in the script portion as well?

Almost there. The current problem is that when I click on a particular zip code. This is the url I get `http://localhost:8888/92606` instead of `http://localhost:8888/getuv.php?param1=92606`

Comment: Call a function onchange of drop down then send value of drop down to PHP page via AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the name attribute, and the onchange method you had was just opening a new window with the param1 as the url.

```
<form action="../">
    <select name="param1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
        <option value="92507">92507</option>
        <option value="30078">30078</option>
        <option value="92606">92606</option>
        <option value="30004">30004</option>
        <option value="32034">32034</option>
        <option value="37160">37160</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<selecton name="zip" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
<option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
<option value="92507">92507</option>
<option value="30078">30078</option>
<option value="92606">92606</option>
<option value="30004">30004</option>
<option value="32034">32034</option>
<option value="37160">37160</option>
</select>
</form>
```

on the page.php you should code like

```
<?php
$code=$_POST['code'];
echo 'the zip code is'.$code;
?>
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed out. I get this instead The requested URL /92507 was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You should try jquery way for frontend.

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
    <option value="92507">92507</option>
    <option value="30078">30078</option>
    <option value="92606">92606</option>
    <option value="30004">30004</option>
    <option value="32034">32034</option>
    <option value="37160">37160</option>
</select>



$("#myList").change(function () {
    var myValue = $("#myList option:selected").val();
    sendToServer(myValue);
});
var sendToServer = function(myValue){
 // Use some ajax
    jQuery.ajax(
        type: "GET",
            url: 'http://host.com/' +'param1='+ myValue,
            beforeSend: function(){ 
                // do something
            },
            success: function(data){
                // success 
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign 'param1' to name in the select tag:

```
code:
```

```html
<form action="../"> <select name = 'param1' onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
    <option value="92507">92507</option>
    <option value="30078">30078</option>
    <option value="92606">92606</option>
    <option value="30004">30004</option>
    <option value="32034">32034</option>
    <option value="37160">37160</option> 
</select> 
</form>
```

Comment: The requested URL /92507 was not found on this server. This is the error I get. I try to print out the zip code.  <?php
$php_variable = $_GET['param1'];
echo 'the zip code is'.$php_variable;
?>

Comment: oh! You need to change the action attribute too and point to your PHP file.

Comment: I did. My php file is called getuv.php `<form action="getuv.php" method="post"> <select name = 'param1' onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">`

Comment: why are you using window.open? It means, you are trying to open a new window on change (which should be a url).